# pytables. Warning accessing a node with f.get_node()

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I am using `python` with `pytables` to read `h5 file`.

So basically what I am doing is this:

```
f = t.open_file(file, mode='r')
root = f.root
obj = f.get_node(root, 'density_100m')
```

The problem is that I am getting a warning, when accessing `get_node`:

```
DataTypeWarning: Unsupported type for attribute 'DIMENSION_LIST' in node 'density_100m'. Offending HDF5 class:
```

It outputs the matrix inside of the node correctly, but the warning is still there.

Here is how the data looks like in [hdfViewer](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/):
[image]

The problem is with this DIMENSION_LIST but I have no idea how to access this node without a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the actual data type of DIMENSION_LIST, my guess is that this file was not created with PyTables and that the DIMENSION_LIST attribute uses a data type that PyTables doesn't know about, such as float16 or something similar.  The warning is not a big deal as long as you do not need to explicitly access this attribute.

As per your specific problem of not displaying the warning, you should use the normal [Python warning hooks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) to suppress this behavior.  Given your code above,

```
import warnings

f = t.open_file(file, mode='r')
root = f.root

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    obj = f.get_node(root, 'density_100m')

# do stuff with obj
```